# ImportError: No module named ssl_match_hostname when importing the docker SDK for Python

Tags: python, docker

In order to use the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html), I'm trying to `import docker` in a Python script, but it's resulting in an `ImportError` with the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/dev/clones8/ipercron-compose/furion/iclib/tests/test_utils/docker_utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    import docker
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .client import Client, AutoVersionClient, from_env # flake8: noqa
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/client.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import api
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .build import BuildApiMixin
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/api/build.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import utils
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .utils import (
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/utils/utils.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .. import tls
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/tls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .ssladapter import ssladapter
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/ssladapter/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .ssladapter import SSLAdapter # flake8: noqa
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docker/ssladapter/ssladapter.py", line 21, in <module>
    from backports.ssl_match_hostname import match_hostname
ImportError: No module named ssl_match_hostname
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "/home/kurt/dev/clones8/ipercron-compose/furion/iclib/tests/test_utils/docker_utils.py"]
[dir: /home/kurt/dev/clones8/ipercron-compose/furion/iclib/tests/test_utils]
[path: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin]
```

The strange thing is that the import does work in other places, for example in an iPython prompt:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import docker

In [2]:
```

Why is the import not working in the first case?

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of python? Have you try to install `docker` in python3? F.e., `pip3 install docker`?

Comment: I do have 2 versions of Python, but as far as I can recall I haven't tried `pip3 install docker`.

Answer (score 53):

Upgrading docker didn't solve the problem for me. Instead, I had to install the backports as Ubuntu package (and uninstall from pip):

```
sudo pip uninstall backports.ssl-match-hostname
sudo apt-get install python-backports.ssl-match-hostname
```

Comment: Same for me in Fedora 29, `sudo dnf reinstall python2-backports-ssl_match_hostname` fixed it.

Comment: on RHEL7 this fixed it by shadowing the flaky system install with a newer local one: `pip2 install --user --upgrade backports.ssl_match_hostname`

Answer (score 8):

I had `backports.ssl-match-hostname` installed locally, which was preventing it from being installed at the system level. I solved it by

```
sudo pip uninstall backports.ssl-match-hostname
```

followed by

```
sudo pip install --upgrade docker
```

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu/Debian, there is a bug related to package upgrade ([bug #893520](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=893520)) at the moment, where the `__init__.py` file is not generated.

Check if the following file exists: `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/__init__.py`

If it does not exist and the package `python-backports.ssl-match-hostname` is installed, then run the following command to generate the missing file:

```
sudo pycompile -p python-backports.ssl-match-hostname
```

Answer (score 6):

The issue could be there because of different versions of Docker-compose and Docker.
First compare the version and upgrade it to make it compatible.

Secondly,you can uninstall the backport package (via pip).

```
sudo pip uninstall backports.ssl-match-hostname
```

and then install it again as a ubuntu package.

```
sudo apt-get install python-backports.ssl-match-hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't install it with other backports packages until fixed (if they fix it)

Seen in https://bitbucket.org/ambv/configparser/issues/17/importerror-when-used-with-other-backports#comment-36669436 :

> Michał Górny
>
> Well, I just wanted to report the core issue here but it seems that
>   other already have learned it the hard way.
>
> Long story short, you can't ever mix pkg_resources namespaces and
>   pkgutil namespaces. It's explained in the Python packaging guide.
>   Attempting to import both is probably the best way to cause random
>   breakage for everyone. You have to decide on one of them, and use it
>   consistently across all packages using the backports namespace.
>
> Now, the backports package seems to serve the sole purpose of claiming
>   the namespace, and it uses pkgutil. So I'd suggest following that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing this from docker-compose:

For me the answer by @CGFoX didn't work, even though this was in the correct direction. When analyzing the issue, we figured that there were two python paths for dist-packages, `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports` and `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports`.

Python was trying to load the module 'ssl_match_hostname' module from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports. But it was not present there:

`drwxr-sr-x   5 root staff  4096 Aug 12 07:46 ./
drwxrwsr-x 130 root staff 12288 Aug 12 07:37 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root staff    75 Nov 14  2018 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--   1 root staff   269 Nov 14  2018 __init__.pyc
drwxr-sr-x   2 root staff  4096 Nov 14  2018 configparser/
drwxr-sr-x   2 root staff  4096 Nov 14  2018 shutil_get_terminal_size/`

But the module is present in the other location.

`x@soumubuntu:~$ ll /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 12 07:19 ./
drwxr-xr-x 78 root root 4096 Aug 12 06:51 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Aug  9 03:05 __init__.py
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  141 Aug 12 07:19 __init__.pyc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 12 07:19 ssl_match_hostname/`

So, I copied it from B->A:

`sudo cp -r /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/ssl_match_hostname/ /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports/`

and voila, docker compose is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain the root cause of the issue.
python looks for 'backports' directory, when it is found, python looks for 'ssl_match_hostname' subdirectory. If it is not found, it is an error.
In other words if one has '/usr/lib.../backports' and no '/usr/lib.../backports/ssl_match_hostname' (any backport installed by apt), it is pointless to use pip to install anything in /usr/local/lib or in /home.

If we have a collision between distro and pip:

```
dpkg-query -S /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/backports
apt remove all_found_packages
pip install whatever_you_need
```

If we have a collision between global and local pip do similar trick.

It is handy to use strace to solve such issues.

Answer (score -2):

I faced the similar issue however was able to resolve by first uninstalling with following commands -

**pip uninstall backports.ssl_match_hostname**

Once it gets uninstalled successfully then use following commands to install docker client with  -

**pip install docker-py**

I hope this would help to resolve this issue

Comment: docker-py is unmaintained. also removing backports is not possible on newer systems where it was installed using system package manager (yum/dnf/...).